# Angular Kendo Grid InCell Editing Capture Edited DataItem

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular6, kendo-ui-angular2

I am new to Kendo Grids for Angular. I am trying to use In-Cell Directive shown [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-directives/) to edit the row and capture the edited data.

Even though I add `kendoGridSaveCommand`, I still don't see the button. More importantly when i make an edit to a row and tab out (or hit enter), I am unable to capture the dataitem. I tried adding `(save)="saveHandler($event)"` to the grid but no luck.

Here is a stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqxzlo

I have added saveHandler method but it's not triggered.

```
saveHandler({dataItem}) {
      console.log("Save Handler Was Clicked");
      console.log(dataItem);
    }
```

How can I extract the edited row? I want to pass it to a service for CRUD operation.

I want to extract the row similar to one done with Remove button (I have logged to the console).

[image]

```
removeHandler({dataItem}) {
      console.log("Remove Handler was Clicked");
      console.log(dataItem);
    }
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could utilize the `cellClose` event which will be triggered once you click outside the edited cell (suited for your current case) or if you want to programmatically `closeCell` will do , read [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/in-cell-editing/)

use it similar to the save event `(cellClose)="cellCloseHandler($event)"`

man i'm not familiar with stack blitz, i tried to add it on your stack blitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mqxzlo-nuzlqp?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks! cellClose did the tricked. I am still unsure why kendoGridSaveCommand button does not show up. I will enquire with Kendo Team.